# How to make a countdown timer on appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, channel-api

I am developing an application (on GAE) that needs a countdown timer and notifies the client side when the timer reaches zero.

To notify the client side i'm using GAE Channel API .

any ideas? (Considering GAE limitations. not using Thread or Timer from Java API).

Comment: is there a reason the client can't do the countdown?  what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The problem is that I have to notify the clients when an server object expires.

Comment: If the server knows when the object will expire, why not just send the time-until-expiry along with the page, and let the client determine when it's expired?

Comment: That's the idea did it using the GAE TaskQueue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much reliability/precision you need, anyway here are a couple of ideas:

1. After saving the server local time on memcache with the respective client ID, send a *"timer-start"* message to the client through the [Channel API](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/java/channel/) handling it client-side via some Javascript counter.  When the timer is over or client has completed its duties , call the server and do your business logic.
2. Use the **countdown** parameter of the [TaskQueue](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html), and before sending the *"timer start"* message to the client, add a task with a given countdown. The added task after n seconds will be triggered and should send the *"timer-over"* message to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just poll for the information from client side? 
Or you can make cron task that run's once a minute and send appropriate message.

depends on how often do you need to do this, whta prcision you need